# Excluding a particular style of element

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have defined a style for `input` elements in HTML,
e.g.

```
input { font-family: Cambria; font-size: 13pt; }
```

So it by default applies to all the `input` elements I write in the page.

Now I want one specific `input` element with no style; can I do that?

Comment: There are probably several old questions, though they can be hard to find due to varying formulations. The point still is that there is no exclusion mechanism in CSS in the sense asked.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela you are wrong about that: if this input is of a different type or has an unique class/ID you can.

Comment: @Knu, you are welcome to post a solution to the question for which this is a duplicate. Just claiming that there is a solution does not help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The element selector has a lower priority than the class selector, so you can just add a class:

```
.special-input { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; }
```

Comment: That does not make the `input` element appear with no style; it just styles it in a specific way.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela well you need to set the styles to whatever the defaults should be; you can't "remove" styles with CSS